# javascript combo box fill second combo error

Tags: javascript, php

I have a rental inspection page I wrote for my work. All the selected
work except anything with more than one. Like bedroom1,bathroom1, fireplace1
works fine as does all the others selections. But when bedroom2,3,4,5,
bathroom2,3,4,5 etc. are selected they do not work at all. I have a work around, just click on the first one then the 2nd etc. uses it.

I have included the bedroom.items.php file at the bottom.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fillSecondCombo()
{
   var combo1 = document.getElementById('Combobox1');
   var combo2 = document.getElementById('Combobox2');
   var selected = combo1.options[combo1.options.selectedIndex].value;
   if (selected == "attic")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/attic.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "basement")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/basement.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "bathroom1")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/bathroom.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "bathroom2")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/bathroom.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "bathroom3")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/bathroom.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "bathroom4")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/bathroom.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "bathroom5")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/bathroom.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "bedroom1")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/bedroom.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "bedroom2")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/bedroom.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "bedroom3")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/bedroom.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "bedroom4")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/bedroom.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "bedroom5")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/bedroom.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "cooling")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/cooling.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "diningroom")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/diningroom.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "electric")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/electric.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "water")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/water.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
    if (selected == "gas")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/gas.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "exterior")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/exterior.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "foundation")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/foundation.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "garage")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/garage.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "heating")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/heating.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "interior")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/interior.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "kitchen")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/kitchen.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "laundry")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/laundry.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "roof")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/roof.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "waterhtr")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/waterhtr.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "livingroom")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/livingroom.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "fireplace1")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/fireplace.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "fireplace2")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/fireplace.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "fireplace3")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/fireplace.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "fireplace4")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/fireplace.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "fireplace5")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/fireplace.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "fireplace10")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/fireplace.items.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "poolspa")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/poolspa.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   if (selected == "other")
   {
    <?php include_once "item.lists/other.item.php"; ?>
   }
   else
   {
    combo2.options.length = 0;
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="space"><br></div>
<div id="container">

<button id="AdvancedButton1" type="button" style="position:absolute;left:19px;top:119px;width:137px;height:44px;z-index:12;" onclick="window.location='main.php'" name="Your Account" value="">
<div style="text-align:center"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px"><b>Main Menu</b></span></div>
</button>
<button id="AdvancedButton2" type="button" style="position:absolute;left:176px;top:119px;width:124px;height:44px;z-index:13;" onclick="window.location='logout.php'" name="Logout" value="">
<div style="text-align:center"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px"><b>Logout</b></span></div>
</button>
<div id="wb_Form1" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:209px;width:302px;height:574px;z-index:14;">
<form name="Form1" method="post" action="make.all.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="Form1" onsubmit="return ValidateForm1(this)">
<textarea name="a4" id="TextArea1" style="position:absolute;left:1px;top:275px;width:279px;height:143px;z-index:0;" rows="7" cols="32" tabindex="4"></textarea>
<div id="wb_Text5" style="position:absolute;left:4px;top:249px;width:152px;height:16px;z-index:1;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Notes: 300 Chars Max.</span></div>
<div id="wb_Text4" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:164px;width:170px;height:16px;z-index:2;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Passed-Needs Repare-N/A:</span></div>
<select name="a2" size="1" id="Combobox2" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:109px;width:280px;height:43px;z-index:3;" tabindex="2">
</select>
<div id="wb_Text3" style="position:absolute;left:4px;top:85px;width:140px;height:16px;z-index:4;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Item Being Inspected:</span></div>
<select name="a1" size="1" id="Combobox1" onchange="fillSecondCombo();return false;" style="position:absolute;left:1px;top:32px;width:279px;height:43px;z-index:5;" tabindex="1">
<option value="<?php include "$dirPath/all.areas.php"; ?>"></option>
</select>
<div id="wb_Text2" style="position:absolute;left:4px;top:0px;width:142px;height:16px;z-index:6;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Area Being Inspected:</span></div>
<div id="wb_Text1" style="position:absolute;left:4px;top:436px;width:59px;height:16px;z-index:7;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Photo:</span></div>
<input type="file" id="FileUpload1" style="position:absolute;left:2px;top:452px;width:279px;height:41px;line-height:41px;z-index:8;" name="userfile[]" tabindex="5">
<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;left:44px;top:513px;width:102px;height:30px;z-index:9;" tabindex="6">
<select name="a3" size="1" id="Combobox3" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:188px;width:280px;height:43px;z-index:10;" tabindex="3">
<option selected value="Passed">Passed</option>
<option value="Needs Repair">Needs Repair</option>
<option value="N/A">N/A</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
<div id="wb_TextArt1" style="position:absolute;left:18px;top:8px;width:285px;height:100px;z-index:15;">
<img src="images/img0018.png" id="TextArt1" alt="Enter Inspection Data" title="Enter Inspection Data" style="width:285px;height:100px;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

bedroom.items.php

```
combo2.options.length = 9;
combo2.options[0] = new Option("Electrical Wall Plugs", "Electrical Wall Plugs");
combo2.options[1] = new Option("Walls and Ceiling", "Walls and Ceiling");
combo2.options[2] = new Option("Floor Covering", "Floor Covering");
combo2.options[3] = new Option("Windows (curtains, blinds, etc...)", "Windows (curtains, blinds, etc...)");
combo2.options[4] = new Option("Doors", "Doors");
combo2.options[5] = new Option("Lighting/Light Fixtures", "Light Fixtures");
combo2.options[6] = new Option("Closet(s)", "Closet(s)");
combo2.options[7] = new Option("Smoke Detector(s)", "Smoke Detector(s)");
combo2.options[8] = new Option("Heating/Cooling", "Heating/Cooling");
```

Comment: Why the down point with no reason? Is there something else I need to add?, Not sure how else to explain it. I have looked around for some time but they didn't quite match this code.

Comment: Hey @bpross. Your question is kind of confusing. It's hard to tell what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: When any combo box 1 items are selected it's suppose to fill the second combo box. They all work except bedroom2,3,4,5 and bathroom2,3,4,5 & fireplace2,3,4,5 bedroom1, bathroom1 & fireplace1 and all other non bedroom, bathroom all work filling the second combo box. If I select any of bedroom2,3,4,5 bathroom2,3,4,5 and fireplace2,3,4,5 they don't fill the second combo box. I can't see why not.

Comment: Can you, please, edit your question to show us your HTML for those `<select>`?

Comment: It's done. All the selected items work except the 3 that have more than 1.

Comment: It's done. As I mentioned all selected items work except the 3 that have more than 1. I don't know enough about the combo box code so I have no idea how it could be changed since all the others work but it's there. The top portion of the code is way to long to add. It has the colors and styles for the boxes etc.

Comment: I'll check back in the morning. Have a good night.

Comment: What did you change to get the other options working? If you find a solution, fill free to add it as an answer.

Comment: I changed nothing. Only the multiples don't work. That's why I asked here. I can't see what the problem is for only those with more than 1 not to work. This is so odd. The work around until I can fix it, if I go to use say bedroom2, I first click on bedroom1 to get the list and then click on bedroom2 the list will stay and work. So odd. I read in searches a couple others were having this happen but no fix was found from many years ago.

Comment: I've also thought about using a preg_match so I would only need one selected routine, but that hasn't been doing too well yet. if (preg_match('/^bedroom(\d+)\items.php/', $workitem, $matches)) {

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem in a jsfiddle, but it works ok there. Probably it's something else with your application. Do you get any kind of error in your browser's console when selecting options 2, 3, ...?

Comment: No errors at all. It just doesn't open the list. Even on Android, Ubuntu and Windows 10. So I'll just have to keep doing the workaround. At least it only one extra click. Just wish I could figure it out. I don't know what a java script fiddle is but Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90137/discussion-between-gustavo-straube-and-bpross).